# Add new buffer after current one

Tags: buffers

How can I create a new buffer just after(next to) the one I am on ?

Let say I have three buffers opened (1, 2, 3) and I am (my cursor) currently in buffer 1. If I add a new buffer (with `:edit` for example) it will open it in buffer 4, but instead I want to open it in buffer 2 without deleting other existent buffers (so maybe buffer 2 and 3 will become 3 and 4, it's a sort of insert).

Are there any way to do this? (I did some research and found nothing). Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to change a buffer number in the first place?

Comment: To switch more easily between buffers with `:bn` and `:bp`

Comment: I think that you are looking for the wrong solution: you would probably be more efficient if you learn other commands than `bn` and `bp` for example [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084326/4194289) might contain some interesting stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to target buffer numbers in order to rearrange them or to say, *"now it contains this file"*.

You could do a `:b 2` + `:%d_` + `:read somefile`, but that won't be enough, you'd also need to clear filetype, filename, local options and variables, syntax highlighting, and so on.

The best thing to do: forget buffer numbers, there is no way to organize them as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned to keep things "in order", using `:argedit` or `:argadd` adds the filename to the list and you can then stick to :n :N for navigation. I usually map a pair of keys (e.g. F3/F4) to mean previous / next so I don't have to keep hitting ESCAPE and : when I'm editing:

```
map! <special> <F3> <C-\><C-o><F3>
map! <special> <F4> <C-\><C-o><F4>
map <special> <F3> :N<Enter>
map <special> <F4> :n<Enter>
```

Yes, I know how lazy that is ...